# Using Unit Triangle to make a triangle with and an area of 1

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to create a function that returns a triangle with an area of 1 when plotted. I'd like to use the "UnitTriangle" function to do so.

I've tried multiplying "UnitTriangle" by 2(1/x), multiplying it by 2(1/(Max[x]-Min[x]), and multiplying by Total[x] but none return what I'm looking for.

```
Triangle[x_] := (2*(1/x))*UnitTriangle[x];
Plot[Triangle[x], {x, -2, 2} , PlotRange -> All]
```

I understand why this isn't working as I'd like (it's evaluating for each x input), but I don't know how to find the base of the triangle from the input list I provide when I plot it.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: So given a height `x`, you want to create a triangle with an area of 1?

Comment: x defined the bounds of the base of the triangle. So the width would be the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
unitAreaTriangle[w_]:=(
  triangle[x_]:=Piecewise[{
    { 4/w^2*x+2/w,-w/2<=x<0},
    {-4/w^2*x+2/w, 0<=x<=w/2},
    {0,True}}];
  Plot[triangle[x],{x,-w,w},PlotRange->All]);
unitAreaTriangle[2]
```

or

```
plotUnitAreaTriangle[w_]:=Plot[
  Piecewise[{
    { 4/w^2*x+2/w,-w/2<=x<0},
    {-4/w^2*x+2/w, 0<=x<=w/2},
    {0,True}}],
  {x,-w,w},PlotRange->All];
plotUnitAreaTriangle[2]
```